# Neo4j / Cypher: Match nodes only if they have a relation with 1 or more other nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having some trouble on this query I am trying to build. I have looked plenty of places over the internet and I couldn't seem to find an answer, so I am asking here.

so here is what my schema somewhat looks like. (sorry for shitty paint diagram)

[image]

The query I want is;

Starting from one Route node, I get multiple RS, and a single OMS from each RS

I want to find all Route nodes which eventually connects to the same (or more) OMS nodes

here is my current query:

```
MATCH (st)--(rs:RS)--(oms:OMS)
WHERE id(st) = 0
with st,rs, oms, collect(oms) as omsn

MATCH (ed:Route)--(rs2:RS)
WHERE ALL(x in omsn WHERE (ed)--(rs2)--(x))

RETURN *
```

And that returns this.

[image]

Which is almost correct, but notice that Route node 21 does not connect to BOTH OMS 4 and 2 so I do NOT want that strand

The result should be something like this instead.

[image]

How would I change my query to accomplish this instead? (Note that the RS node in the middle is necessary for some other stuff I am also doing, so I cannot remove those. I have gotten it working, though with just a 2 layer heiarchy, but that is not what I need.)

edit: simple insertion query

```
CREATE (a:Route)-[:rel]->(b:RS)-[:rel]->(c:OMS)

CREATE (a)-[:rel]->(d:RS)-[:rel]->(e:OMS)

CREATE (f:Route)-[:rel]->(g:RS)-[:rel]->(c)
CREATE (f)-[:rel]->(i:RS)-[:rel]->(e)
CREATE (f)-[:rel]->(k:RS)-[:rel]->(hfg:OMS)

CREATE (l:Route)-[:rel]->(m:RS)-[:rel]->(c)
CREATE (l)-[:rel]->(o:RS)-[:rel]->(e)
CREATE (l)-[:rel]->(asd:RS)-[:rel]->(dsf:OMS)
CREATE (l)-[:rel]->(ds:RS)-[:rel]->(gdg:OMS)

MATCH (m:OMS) WHERE id(m) = 4
CREATE (:Route)-[:rel]->(:RS)-[:rel]->(m)

RETURN *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 tips for working with Cypher.

1) Run a test with `RETURN *` after each `WITH` to verify you are returning what you want.

2) Look at the text table to verify the format of your return data.

The problem with your query is this part

```
MATCH (st)--(rs:RS)--(oms:OMS)
WHERE id(st) = 0
with st,rs, oms, collect(oms) as omsn
```

- (st) is a single node, so 1 row of data
- (rs) is two diffrent nodes, so now you have 2 rows of data
- each (oms) node is one node off of an (rs) node. So 1 row for each (rs).
- RETURN * will return 1 * 2 * COLLECT(1) as 1 = 2 rows

  - Note here that you have 2 rows of data, each with 1 distinct (oms) node

The solution here is to either do

- Use COLLECT(rs) in the WITH to collapse those 2 rows into 1, so that the 2 (oms) nodes also get collected into the same list (note, this may contain duplicate oms nodes. use COLLECT(DISTINCT oms) if this will be a problem)
- Only carry over COLLECT(oms) in the WITH part. The rest will be matched again in the following match anyways.

Final note. You know the direction of the relationships; Include it in the Cypher for better/cleaner performance.

Comment: I've tried both methods you suggested, it seems to either just return the entire thing again, or return none at all. for the first method i tried doing this. `with st, collect(rs) as rsn` `MATCH (ed:Route)--(rs2:RS)--(oms:OMS)` `WHERE ALL(x in rsn WHERE (oms)--(x))` which seems to have returned nothing.