# Cypher: WHERE ALL Not working as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So my query is for a "superpath finding problem".

The relevant nodes here are;

**route:** The overall path object

**tlroutesegment:** The logical link between the route and the different segments (which compose the full path) *(ps: I know this could be better represented using a relationship, however the database is just made this way :S)*

**oms:** The PHYSICAL path segments itself

**validochpath:** More or less irrelevant for this question; Top level entity of routes

So on to the actual problem I am having; below is a WORKING solution to the above, HOWEVER, I wanted to optimize the query a bit by reducing the # of routes we have to search through in the 4th line here.

```
MATCH (vp:validochpath {"some ID HERE"})-->(ort:route)<-- 
(rs:tlroutesegment)-->(oms:oms)
WITH collect(oms) AS omsNodes

MATCH (ort:route)
WHERE ALL(x in omsNodes WHERE (ort)<--(:tlroutesegment)-->(x))
WITH ort

MATCH (ort)--(vp:validochpath)

RETURN *
```

This is what the new query looks like, as you can see I use the relation to filter out much of the route nodes.

```
MATCH (vp:validochpath {onepID:"some ID HERE"})-->(ort:route)<-- 
(rs:tlroutesegment)-->(oms:oms)<--(rs2:tlroutesegment)

WITH rs2, collect(oms) AS omsNodes

MATCH (rs2)-->(ort2:route)
WHERE ALL(x in omsNodes WHERE (x)<--(:tlroutesegment)-->(ort2))

MATCH (ort2)--(vp:validochpath)

RETURN *
```

The problem is, this query does not seem to filter out any nodes with the WHERE ALL and just returns everything.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, the `WHERE` clause accepts all matches.

From the first `MATCH` clause, we know that `rs2` is a `tlroutesegment` and that all the nodes in `omsNodes` are related to `rs2`. From the second `MATCH` clause, we also know that `ort2` is related to `rs2`. Your `WHERE` clause is checking that all the nodes in `omsNodes` are related to a `tlroutesegment` that is also related to `ort2`. Since `rs2` is a `tlroutesegment`, this test always succeeds.

If you want to test for the existence of paths with `tlroutesegment` nodes that are *different* than `rs2`, try this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ALL(x in omsNodes WHERE
  SIZE([(x)<--(y:tlroutesegment)-->(ort2) WHERE y <> rs2 | y]) > 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, for further clarification on my intentions here is a question i asked previously about the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804968/neo4j-cypher-match-nodes-only-if-they-have-a-relation-with-1-or-more-other-no

the query that worked in the end is the first one posted in this topic, but i find that it took way too long and i am trying to think of a method to pre-filter some of the ROUTE nodes that you are required to search.